# Jest mocking module

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for a node application using Jest.
The Node code is using a third party library to log information.

The library has a function getLogger which you should call to return a logger object.

I am trying to mock the calls for that library and detect its calls in my unit test.
The node code is as follows:

```
const logger = require('third-party-libary').getLogger('myModule')
....
function submitSomething() {
   ....
   logger.info('log something')
}
```

In my Jest unit test, I tried to mock those logger calls in many different ways, with no success, and always come back as "logger is not defined"

I tried:

```
jest.mock('third-party-library');
const loggerFactory = require('third-party-library');
const logger = {
   error: jest.fn(),
   info: jest.fn()
};
loggerFactory.getLogger.mockImplementation(() => logger);
```

But it always return error :

> cannot find "info" for null object

I tried this as well:

```
jest.mock('third-party-library')
const loggerFactory = require('third-party-library');
const logger = {
   error: jest.fn(),
   info: jest.fn()
};
loggerFactory.getLogger = () => logger
```

I tried this:

```
jest.mock('third-party-library')
    const loggerFactory = require('third-party-library');
    const logger = {
       error: jest.fn(),
       info: jest.fn()
    };
    loggerFactory.getLogger = jest.fn(() => logger)
```

With the same error
I switched between the jest.mock to make it after the require, with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works fine, just note that your code creates `logger` *as soon as it runs* so the mock for `getLogger` has to be in place **before** the code is `required`:

```js
jest.mock('third-party-library');
const loggerFactory = require('third-party-library');
const logger = {
   error: jest.fn(),
   info: jest.fn()
};
// const { submitSomething } = require('./code');  <= would NOT work here
loggerFactory.getLogger.mockReturnValue(logger);
const { submitSomething } = require('./code');  // <= works here

test('submitSomething', () => {
  submitSomething();
  expect(logger.info).toHaveBeenCalledWith('log something');  // Success!
});
```